# updatePayloadWithEmbeddedBelongsTo in EmbeddedRecordsMixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use and understand how `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` does to sideload nested JSON, specifically for the `belongsTo` relationship. Looking at the code in tag:v1.0.0-beta.8, this line puzzles me:
[emberjs L521](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/embedded_records_mixin.js#L521)
because in the similar method for the `hasMany` relationship, 
[emberjs L487](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/embedded_records_mixin.js#L487) , an underscore prefix is added to `embeddedTypeKey` to indicate that this record is sideloaded, therefore not primary to the payload.

Why is that not needed for the `belongsTo` relationship?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a really good theory for you, but then I proved it had issues.  There is likely an issue due to that very thing.  Here's an embedded set of data that's all screwed up because of your statement.  (`orange - green` and `purple - gold` is wrong, check out the second example for what it should look like, or dig through the json)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/732/edit

Switching it to a different name, fixes it

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo'),
  colour: DS.belongsTo('color')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/733/edit

So, valid question, it's a bug.